# Wifi works only on safe mode on pixel 3XL

Tags: wi-fi, safe-mode, google-pixel-3-xl

I'm an happy owner of the Google Pixel 3XL. It's been working like a charm for ages, but since a few weeks, the WiFi & Bluetooth started to fail after a few hours for system uptime.

I first thought about [an hardware issue](https://fr.ifixit.com/R%C3%A9ponses/Afficher/420773/Where+is+the+pixel+wifi+antenna#answer490888), but both the WiFi & Bluetooth works in Safe mode. Is there anything I can do to fix this without making a full reset of the device?

Comment: Based on your description you Wifi does not work if you reboot the device, but it works if you reboot the device to safe mode is this correct?

Comment: @Robert it works _sometimes_ on reboot, and _always_ on safe mode

Comment: Have you tried doing a Network Reset from the resets menu?

Comment: @acejavelin yes, but it ain't getting better

Comment: At this point the next step should be a full factory reset. Is it completely stock? If not, I would factory default and reflash the stock firmware... If it is, then I would suspect a hardware failure likely related to heat micro-cracking. In Safe Mode the processor is kept throttled in addition to preventing some software from loading.